# Dependencies for displaytag library

Tags: java, log4j, displaytag

I am integrating the **displaytag** library into my web application. I have used the library at my work, but what I am currently building does not have it currently. When I went to review the dependencies for installation of the library, I noticed that it had the following listed...

```
commons-logging
commons-lang
commons-collections
commons-beanutils
log4j
```

I believe that I have provided all of the **commons** dependencies that it needs, but I noticed that it also has **log4j**. I am not currently using log4j as my logging, so I am curious if it will in fact not work if I dont have log4j set up, or if it will be fine and just needs it available.

It doesn't really mention in the installation documentation provided at

[Display Tag Installation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/install.html)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag/dependencies.html) seems to indicate that log4j is *Optional* (at least for version 1.2).

The same page mentions that slf4j is *Not optional*, indicating that the library has been coded using [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org).  If so, instead of log4j, any other logging provider can be substituted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Raghuram, although log4j is optional for displaytag and slf4j is not optional, the slf4j in turn has a dependency on log4j and it is not optional. [Link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30)

Basically displaytag needs log4j indirectly as mentioned [here](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/displaytag-examples/dependencies.html).